# USB Connections Pop-up is missing

Tags: popup

So I had this problem around when I started to root my phones (which is recently). Usually there's 2 pop-up that would shown up whenever I connected my phone to computer, but after I rooted it the pop-up is missing (and yes I've activated the usb debugging option, restarted my phone, changed the usb cable and even downloaded a brand new usb driver on my computer). Any solutions or there's something to do with the root? (for your informations my phone is Evercoss A65B)

Comment: Have you tried revoking USB Debugging authorizations under developer options.

Comment: yes I've tried that but to no avail. But before that let me say thank you for your answer.